# Data Not saving in real time database flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where i need to save data in real time database ,  i have setup code for authentication , storage and realtime database , auth and storage work fine but not the latter ,
i have tried different approach to make realtime db work but unfortunately nothing was successful , any help would be appreciated guys thank you.

- This is how i init firebase

```
 FirebaseApp app;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'SecondaryApp',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          appId: '1:729669525962:android:b878xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          apiKey: 'AIzaSyD0w6UnBrWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
          messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          projectId: 'groceryfxxxxxxxxf6'
      )
  );
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: UserRegistrationScreen(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}
```

- part 2

```
class _UserRegistrationScreenState extends State<UserRegistrationScreen> {

 DatabaseReference itemRef;
 final firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');

 }
```

- This is how i save data

```
  BuyerModel model = new BuyerModel(
                              fullName,phone,country,state,city,address,
                              email,'online','Buyer', downloadUrl,DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
                              firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid);
                            itemRef.child(firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid).set(model);
```

- This is the buyer model

```
 class BuyerModel {
  String fullName;
  String phone;
  String country;
  String state;
  String city;
  String address;
  String email;
  String status;
  String accountType;
  String profileImage;
  String timeStamp;
  String userUid;

  BuyerModel(this.fullName,this.phone,this.country,this.state,this.city,
      this.address,this.email,this.status,this.accountType,this.profileImage,
      this.timeStamp,this.userUid);
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, although ideally we should see `BuyerModel` to be certain. Or you can simplify the code. If `itemRef.child(firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid).set(true)` also doesn't work, you know the model isn't the problem. If that's the case, you might want to check the logcat output for permission errors in the `set()` or attach a completion handler as shown here: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: You tagged with `flutter` and with `kotlin`. That makes no sense, as you're likely using only one of these. So please update your tags to only contain what is relevant to the problem we're looking at here.

Comment: Sorry i actully put the tag 'kotlin' because when i createa flutter project , it asks me what to use besides dart , i use kotlin , i will cange it thank you

Comment: That's the problem , for example when i used to get a null exception somewhere , it shows , now it dosnt show anything as error in logcat , that's why i kept trying ..but nothing

Comment: In Flutter I don't think the Firebase SDK knows how to write custom classes like `BuyerModel`. I usually end up with `fromSnapshot` and `toMap` methods to map back and forth. But I would expect the SDK to throw an error when you pass an object it can't serialize.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter I don't think the Firebase SDK knows how to write custom classes like `BuyerModel`. I usually end up with `fromSnapshot` and `toMap` methods to map back and forth.

An example of such a class:

```
class Question {
  HUser owner;
  String title;
  List<String> answers;
  int timeInSeconds;
  String key;

  Question(String this.title, List<String> this.answers, this.timeInSeconds, { this.owner }) {
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String,dynamic>{
      "owner": owner?.uid,
      "title": title,
      "answers": answers,
      "timeInSeconds": timeInSeconds
    };
  }

  Question.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot): assert(snapshot != null),
    title = snapshot.value["title"],
    timeInSeconds = snapshot.value["timeInSeconds"],
    owner = snapshot.value["owner"] != null ? HUser(snapshot.value["owner"]) : null,
    key = snapshot.key;
}
```

I see now that I still need to read the `answers` back from the snapshot. That might explain a bug in my app.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time , one last thing , please now to pass my model to set() method , should toMap() , or just the buyermodel directly as i did before in my code ?

Comment: You should then pass the `toMap()`  return value to the `set`method.

Comment: i actually did so i copied pasted your model class , just have to change to my own values , but still nothing is working

Comment: "nothing is working" is really hard to help with. I merely showed my class as an example, you'll definitely need to make you own class that does a similar conversion.  When you step through your code after doing that, does it do what you expect it to do? Which line is the first one that doesn't? What values do all variables have there?

Comment: I have experience using firebase with java and kotlin and and it is little similar to how to do the same in flutter , but i have added all necessary components for it to work , because auth and storage work fine , i have firebase_database plugin , did everything , it is confusing me and i got stuck at that point